# Log Power Rule (Substituting a 2^X)

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, discrete-logarithms

Always approach Logarithms with uncertainty. a bit confused by Log of power rule. Hope to receive some simple clarifications. Found this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97972/show-that-t2n-big-theta-of-3n) very interesting. Where we basically have $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$. as we plug in $2^n$, shouldn't it become  \begin{equation}  \Theta(2^{n^{\log_2 3}}) \end{equation}.

If so, we can't do any further simplification, can we ?
or it is correct to have 
$T(2^n) = \Theta(2^{n\log_2 3})$. 
if so, what if we plug in $2^{n^{n}}$, what should it be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T(2^n)$ is not $2^{n^{\log_23}}$, it's $(2^n)^{\log_23}=2^{n\log_23}$.

Comment: Ok, How should I convince myself ?  which means if we plug in $2^{n^{n}}$, it would be $(2^{n^{n}})^{\log_23} $. can we simplify this one?

Comment: $\log_23$ is a number just like, say, $27$: would you make the same suggestions with $27$?

Comment: It is unclear to me what "simplify" means to you. To me, $(2^{n^n})^{\log_23}=2^{n^n\log_23}$ is as simple as it gets.

Comment: I was trying to get it into a more "pretty" form where we can/may do some calculations with. For example, when it was $2^n$, we can turn it into $ T(2^n) = \(2^{n\log_2 3})  ->T (3^n)$

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, it's the same with $2^{n^n\log_23}=\left(2^{\log_23}\right)^{n^n}=3^{n^n}$.